# can i access Module class method from controller just by calling the method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, include, request

I have the following module inside lib/api_client:

request.rb

```
module APIClient

  class Request
    require 'digest/sha1'
    require "net/http"
    require "uri"

    def self.venues_response
      ...
    end

  end
end
```

wich i include in my controller class like this:

```
class VenuesController < ApplicationController

  include APIClient
```

I'd like to access it's methods from inside venues_controller like this:

```
venues_response
```

But i get the following error:

```
undefined method `venues_response' for #<VenuesController:0x007f9ee058ad00>
```

And if i try this:

```
Request.venues_response
```

I get:

```
uninitialized constant VenuesController::Request
```

The only way seems to be this:

```
APIClient::Request.venues_response
```

Is there a way to make the call simpler? Am i missing something?

EDIT:

Forgot to mention autoloading is already added on application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: try autoloading the lib directory. Inside application.rb, add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

Comment: Im already doing it, @forthowin. Sorry i missed it in the description.

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? Is it `No Class Request` or `No Method venues_response for Request`?

Comment: Hi @evanbikes. I just edit my question to add the info you where asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `request.rb` to `api_client.rb`.

Comment: this made it. Thanks @forthowin.